# Python 2.7 listbox insert type

Tags: python, tkinter

Can I use type 'int' in second argument of listbox in Tkinter?  I can't find it in any documentation.

```
x = int(584)
listBox.insert(0, x)
```

Comment: did you try it? Any errors? What's your question?

Comment: Yes and sometimes weird error occurred. But I don't know if this was a reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have tweaked the English in the post.  Have you tried it using it ?  What error do you get ?

Comment: TclError: bad option "setinteger but got "0.0"

Comment: @Tkinter: the code you posted can't possibly give that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but try this:

```
from Tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

listBox = Listbox(screen)
listBox.pack()

x = int(584)

listBox.insert(0, x)

mainloop()
```